# Magento import hangs

Tags: import, csv, magento-1.9.3.2

I am having some problems with base import on a Magento website. Problem is that the import hangs and remains stuck on the Please wait message.

I checked, the var/importexport has all the necessary permissions, the csv file even appears after I hit the import button.

I checked all the different solutions found on forums and on stackexchange, but none of them seem to be the issue in my case. There are no errors on the browser console, in the logs, on the server logs, the file is UTF-8, memory limit is set to 2048. I tried to leave just one line in the import file, it's the same. I exported all the products and then tried to reimport the file without ever opening it: same. I left just one product in the export file and then tried to reimport it: same issue.

So I think it's there is no problem with CSV file, it has to do something with magento failing to process the data.